# Symplectic resolutions amongst cotangent bundles

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, resolution-of-singularities, geometric-representation-theory, holomorphic-symplectic, symplectic-resolutions

It is known that a generalized flag variety $X=T^*(G/P)$ is a (symplectic) resolution of singularities of its affinization $X^\text{aff}\mathrel{:=}\operatorname{Spec}(H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X))$. In type A, this affinization is the closure of a nilpotent orbit, and in other types, it is finite over it. Moreover, it is conjectured in Kaledin's paper ([Geometry and topology of symplectic resolutions](https://doi.org/10.1090/pspum/080.2/2483948), Conj. 1.3) that these are the only cotangent bundles of smooth projective varieties which are resolutions of their affinization.

As this paper was written some time ago, I am interested in whether any progress has been made towards proving this conjecture?

**NB** Everything is assumed under complex numbers, the flag variety, and the symplectic structure.

Comment: What is "this property"?  For example, is the question which cotangent bundles $T^*(M)$ have the property that their affinisation is the normalisation of the closure of a nilpotent orbit for some reductive group $G$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have changed the question to make it more explicit now.

Answer (score 3):

I think @Joel is saying the following (this was too long for a comment, so I put it as an answer):

Given a **conical** symplectic resolution $X\mathrel{:=}T^*M \rightarrow X^\text{aff}$ whose $\mathbb{C}^*$-action contracts the fibres of $X$ with weight 1, the ring of global functions
$R=H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ has a set of homogenous generators $\{x_1,\dotsc,x_n\}$ with maximal weight 1. (**)

The last fact, together with the normality of the ring $R$, is precisely saying that $X^\text{aff}$ is a conical symplectic singularity with maximal weight 1, thus the Namikawa's theorem applies, stating that $X^\text{aff}$ must be a closure of a normal nilpotent orbit in a semisimple $\mathfrak{g}$. Then, by
[Fu_Symplectic Resolutions for Nilpotent Orbits (Theorem 0.1)](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0205048),
we indeed have $X \cong T^*(G/P),$ for some parabolic subgroup $P$ of $G$ (and $\operatorname{Lie}(G)=\mathfrak{g}$). Moreover, $X^\text{aff}=\overline{O}_P\mathrel{:=}\operatorname{Im}(\mu),$ where $$\mu:T^*(G/P)\rightarrow \mathfrak{g}^*\cong \mathfrak{g}$$ is the moment map of the $G$-action (and $\mathfrak{g}^*\cong \mathfrak{g}$ is obtained via Killing form).

Though, what still worries me is that the argument above **does not** cover resolutions
$$X=T^*(G/P) \rightarrow X^\text{aff},$$ where the induced map $X^\text{aff}\rightarrow \overline{\mathcal{O}_P}$ is not an isomorphism, but rather a finite cover. This is a general setup, and in some cases (e.g. when $G=\operatorname{SL}_n$), this map is indeed an isomorphism.

Having this in mind, perhaps the statement (**) about the weights of global functions is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In [A characterization of nilpotent orbit closures among symplectic singularities](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.06105), Namikawa proved that a weight 1 conical symplectic singularity must be a nilpotent orbit closure.

So I guess that this implies that a weight 1 conical symplectic resolution (which just means that the affinization is a weight 1 conical symplectic singularity) must be the cotangent bundle of a partial flag variety.  (I think that it is known that if a nilpotent orbit closure admits a symplectic resolution, then this symplectic resolution must be a cotangent bundle.)

Comment: Joel, could you please check whether what I am saying in the answer below is what you are saying. In particular, there is an issue (see the question at the end).